# Android AAPT not running from within Android Studio version 0.8.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Here's my bash profile on mac:

```
# Android Stuff
export ANDROID_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:"$ANDROID_HOME"/platform-tools:"$ANDROID_HOME"/build-tools/19.1.0/
```

I am using AS 0.8.2, I get the following error in Gradle console when I try to run the build target:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':makerfile'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am not sure this link will help us. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791525/compiling-error-with-android-studio"