# Compiling error with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, compiler-errors, aapt

I'm trying compile a android application with Android Studio in linux. But I'm get the following errors:

Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''

How to solve this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589844/android-studio-1-0-2-not-building-appmergedebugresources-error 
In short, you need to install a few libraries in your system.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using a 64-bit machine. According to:

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html

You have to install [libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386]